# Как настроить промежуточную сортировку?

Tags: javascript

Есть JSON:

```
[{
  "price": 12000,
  "seller": "Agency One"
},
{
  "price": 12000,
  "seller": "Agency Two"
},
{
  "price": 12000,
  "seller": "Agency Three",
  "priority": true
},
{
  "price": 11999,
  "seller": "Another one agency"
}]
```

Я этот объект могу отсортировать по цене и тогда порядок цен будет таков, что сперва будет цена 11999, а затем несколько объектов с ценой 12000. И в этом конкретном объект с `priority = true` будет в самом конце. То есть, так:

1. Another one agency - 11999
2. Agency One - 12000
3. Agency Two - 12000
4. Agency Three - 12000 **(priority)**

Я же хочу сделать так, чтобы объект с `priority = true` был первым среди всех объектов с ценой 12000. То есть, так:

1. Another one agency - 11999
2. Agency Three - 12000 **(priority)**
3. Agency One - 12000
4. Agency Two - 12000

Как это сделать и возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    "price": 12000,
    "seller": "Agency One"
  },
  {
    "price": 12000,
    "seller": "Agency Two"
  },
  {
    "price": 12000,
    "seller": "Agency Three",
    "priority": true
  },
  {
    "price": 11999,
    "seller": "Another one agency"
  }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.price == b.price) {
    var pA = a.priority? 0 : 1;
    var pB = b.priority? 0 : 1;
    return pA - pB;
  } else {
    return a.price - b.price;
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

P.S. Относительный порядок следования "Agency One" и "Agency Two" не гарантируется, так как с точки зрения сортировки - они одинаковые. Для сохранения пoрядка следования таких элементов в отсортированном массиве, можно пронумеровать элементы массива перед сортировкой и использовать их порядковые номера как третье условие.

Comment: Всё настолько просто? Спасибо!